# Embedding a form into a MultiPage tab in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel 2010.  I have already created and tested 2 complex forms `frmA` and `frmB`. They run and then save data to the workbook when user hits <kbd>Apply</kbd> or <kbd>OK</kbd>. Now my user wants `frmA` to be able to call `frmB`, do some work, then return to `frmA`.  I thought it might look professional if they could be on a `MultiPage`, but I don’t want to rebuild and retest these forms.

Is there anyway I can create a 2-tab `MultiPage` form and then make `frmA` appear on the first tab, `frmB` appear on the second?  Then I can simply handle the communication between the two instead of recoding.

Or maybe I can just paste all the objects and code from each form onto the tabs and do some object renaming.  The retesting will be extensive, though.

If not, I will have to do `frmA.show`, (user clicks Open `frmB` button), `frmA.Hide`, `frmB.Initialize`, `frmB.Show`, (do some work, hit <kbd>Apply</kbd>/<kbd>OK</kbd>/<kbd>Cancel</kbd>), (update spreadsheet with changes), `frmB.Hide`/`Unload`, (`frmA.Initialize` due to changes), `frmA.Show`.  I have not gotten this to work properly yet – `frmA` disappears and doesn’t come back, but I will work on it if the `MultiPage` is not possible.

Maybe you can save me time by pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: To answer your question, no you cannot embed one userform in another using Excel VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am accepting @guitarthrower 's answer:
To answer your question, no you cannot embed one userform in another using Excel VBA. –  guitarthrower